Does the cli command spl-token support priority fees?
Does the spl-token cli package currently support setting priority fees?

It does as of version 3.4.1 using the --with-compute-unit-price flag. Try running:
$ spl-token --with-compute-unit-price 1 create-token


Currently spl-token does not support setting a custom priority fee
